# Button doesn't appear correctly on page

Tags: jquery, css

The page in question is: http://ww2.hawaiidiscount.com/Thanks/tabid/600/Default.aspx

There is a button on this page that has to appear under the text "Thank you for your order. You will now be redirected to our payment page." but for some reason it doesn't appear. The code for this button is on the page:

```
<input value="Please Click Here if you are not Automatically Redirected to our Payment Page" style="display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top: -96%;" onclick="recordAdrollSegments()" type="submit">
```

I tried removing margin-top: -96%; but it still doesn't show up. Is there a way to make this button appear in a visible place of the page?

Comment: i could not find this button being rendered on link you provided.

Comment: very simple, there is no button element in your html.
You cannot have an input field as button element.

Comment: @damianocelent `<input type="submit">` _**is**_ a button. (but there isn't one of those either)

Answer (score 1):

You need to say to your browser that it is a button, a submit button within the form.
You need to do this, like this: `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` 
Then it's up to you how to handle the form submission.

Comment: If you scroll the ridiculously long input tag you'll see that after the `value`, and the `style`, _and_ the `onclick`, there is indeed a `type="submit"`. Never mind that inline style and inline onclick are terrible development practices, I personally always put "type" _immediately_ after "input".